# Failing to connect to Orion Context Instance through NGSI Updater Widget

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I have a running instance of the Orion Context Broker GE in a CentOS 6.5 server. Apparently it's working fine: I can make REST queries through a web REST Client, make entities with **updateContext** operation and retrieve information about them with **queryContext**.

The thing is that I am trying to link Wirecloud GE with my Orion instance using the NGSI Updater widget. I have updated the widget's settings with my instance URL as follows:

**NGSI Server :        http://my_ip:1026**

**Entity Id Filter:      .***

But it's not able to make a connection to it. After a while it shows me an error dialog:

**Fail querying the server: InvalidResponse:**

**Unexpected error code: undefined**

In the terminal of the instance, when I make a query through a REST client, it shows me the transaction being made, but nothing appears when i try to connect to it through the NGSI Updater Widget.

I don´t know if the problem is from the configuration of my orion context broker instance, or from the widget. For the installation of the instance I followed the steps at: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [NGSI Source operator](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/ngsi-source-operator) and the [NGSI Updater widget](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/ngsi-updater-widget) are going to be updated providing better feedback. This should take less than a week, stay tuned.

Meanwhile, as you can access your context broker using a Rest Client, I guess your problem is related with the connectivity of with your server. The NGSI Updater widget make requests through the WireCloud proxy, so the WireCloud server needs access rights over your instance, check your firewall rules.